# Automatically created list from printed objects

Tags: list, printing, sum

I'm new to Python and am learning via edX and trying to solve ProjectEuler math problems.  The second problem is about summing all even Fibonacci numbers that are less than 4,000,000.  I was able to solve this problem with Python, but not in a way that was satisfying to me.

First I defined a fib function:

```
def fib(n):
if n == 0:
    return 0
elif n == 1:
    return 1
else:
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Then, I was able to print all even Fibonacci numbers with value less than 4,000,000:

```
n = 0
while True:
if fib(n) < 40000000 and fib(n) % 2 == 0:
    print(fib(n))
    n = n+1
elif fib(n) < 4000000 and fib(n) % 2 != 0:
    n = n+1
else:
    break
```

Then, I manually formed a list from what was printed and summed the list.  The problem is that I don't want to have to do that.  I want the computer to form the list as it goes and then sums up the value.  Anyone know how I can do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a generator that produces fib numbers, then just take from it while the numbers are less than 4 million (`4e6`):

```
import itertools

def fib(n):
  if n == 0: return 0
  elif n == 1: return 1
  else: return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

# A generator function that lazily produces new fib numbers
def gen_fibs():
  n = 1
  while True:
    yield fib(n) 
    n += 1

# Take from the generator while n is less than 4 million
fibs = itertools.takewhile(lambda n: n <= 4e6, gen_fibs())

# Keep all the evens
even_fibs = (n for n in fibs if n % 2 == 0)

# Then print the sum of even fibs
print(sum(even_fibs))
```

There may be a way to get around defining the generator manually, but this is still fairly neat. If `range` had a 0-arity version that produced an infinite list, I could have reduced the first part down to a generator expression instead, but such is life.